# Path.repo not being recognized by nodes in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot, data-recovery

I am currently trying to create snapshot of my elasticsearch cluster. I have followed the documentation and proceded to add:

path.repo: ["/data/snapshot"]

to all the elasticsearch.yml config files of my 4 nodes. However after restarting the nodes, said configuration is not being recognized.

when running GET http://ipaddress/_nodes/settings?pretty

I can see the entire configuration of all 4 nodes and this is what i get in the path attribute for all 4:

```
"path": {
          "data": "/usr/local/elasticsearch/data",
          "logs": "/usr/local/elasticsearch/logs",
          "home": "/usr/local/elasticsearch"
        }
```

They are all running as services and even though the config file is clearly being taken into account I went as far as including the following within the starting daemin options:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-d -p $PID_FILE -Des.default.config=$CONF_FILE -Des.default.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.default.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.default.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.default.path.work=$WORK_DIR -Des.default.path.conf=$CONF_DIR  -Des.default.path.repo=$REPO_DIR"
```

I have no idea whats going on and have spent almost 2 days trying stuff out and reading through other experiences with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using a different version on java on 1 node. Make sure to verify this as it can drive you really insane.

Check with:

java -version

And then make sure its included in the /etc/init.d/elasticsearch file like so:

```
# The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME (if JAVA_HOME is not defined in $DEFAULT)
JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ /usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.8-oracle/ /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-x64 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.7-oracle/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/ /usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
```

Hope this helps somebody